# MySQL minus previous row with conditions

Tags: mysql, window-functions

In the table below, I'd like to minus the previous rows date from the current rows date as long as the MPAN columns match, also if the result was to be over 365 I'd like it to max as 365.

We're using MySQL and PHP to try and calculate these and we could do with some guidance on how to achieve it.

**Source**

| MPAN | Current_Supplier | EAC | EAC_EFD | Days Applicable | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID1 | TGPL | 96.7 | 22/05/2021 | 0 | 0.26 |
| ID1 | TGPL | 28009.9 | 26/11/2021 | 0 | 148.74 |
| ID1 | TGPL | 30771.2 | 23/05/2022 | 0 | 16.61 |
| ID2 | TGPL | 191.9 | 22/05/2021 | 0 | 0.53 |
| ID2 | TGPL | 217.9 | 26/08/2021 | 0 | 0.8 |
| ID2 | TGPL | 118.1 | 26/11/2021 | 0 | -0.56 |
| ID2 | TGPL | 38 | 25/02/2022 | 0 | -0.35 |
| ID2 | TGPL | 18.2 | 23/05/2023 | 0 | 0.3 |

**Desired result**

| MPAN | Current_Supplier | EAC | EAC_EFD | Days Applicable | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID1 | TGPL | 96.7 | 22/05/2021 | 365 | 0.26 |
| ID1 | TGPL | 28009.9 | 26/11/2021 | 188 | 148.74 |
| ID1 | TGPL | 30771.2 | 23/05/2022 | 178 | 16.61 |
| ID2 | TGPL | 191.9 | 22/05/2021 | 365 | 0.53 |
| ID2 | TGPL | 217.9 | 26/08/2021 | 96 | 0.8 |
| ID2 | TGPL | 118.1 | 26/11/2021 | 92 | -0.56 |
| ID2 | TGPL | 38 | 25/02/2022 | 91 | -0.35 |
| ID2 | TGPL | 18.2 | 23/05/2023 | 365 | 0.3 |

Thanks.

Comment: Explain each output value - now some of them contradicts your task description..

Comment: What's the relevance of sample data for Current_Supplier, EAC and Value? These columns don't seem to be related to any part of your question?

Comment: Sorry, the only columns that matter in this case are the column for EAC_EFD & MPAN and I want the number of days difference between each subsequent meter read.The data is just a rolling 12 month read value for the amount of energy an electricity meter has used in its previous 12 month period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use MySQL 8 then you can use window function `LAG` returned value from previous row:

```
select 
    id, d,
    LEAST(
      COALESCE(
        DATEDIFF(d, lag(d) over (partition by id order by d)), 365
      ), 
    365)
from tbl;
```

For prevent numbers greater then 365 use `LEAST` function and `COALESCE` for prevent NULL values

[SQL online test](https://sqlize.online/sql/mysql80/c496865ec36151a1b7dbf4385cc39612/)